# Using regex to search for an IP in stndout that wraps to next line

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a python script that logs into a PaloAlto firewall and blocks or removes an IP address from an address group. It then performs a "verification" that the action occurred using re.shearch match from the output to the IP address in question to see if the action was successful.

I'm running into an issue where I'm getting inconsistent or incorrect results because when I search the standard output from firewall the length of the ssh terminal causes the text to wrap to the next line.

Below is an example firewall output.

```
[Blocked IPS] 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 19
2.168.1.5 192.168.1.6 192.168.1.7 192.168.1.8 192.168.1.9 192.16
8.1.10 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12 192.168.1.13 192.168.1.14 192.1
68.1.15 192.168.1.16 192.168.1.17 192.168.1.18 192.168.1.19
```

Below is my simple search where I look for the IP address in the output from the firewall.

```
re.search(ipAddress, output):
```

You can see my dilemma. If I'm searching for "192.168.1.5" or "192.168.1.10"  then it will fail due to the wrapping of the text in the output.

I need a regex that will the entire string even if it wraps to the next line but I haven't been able to create or find anything that works.

I've only been working in python for about a year and am pretty much self taught. I've just started getting into using regex.

Thanks in advance for helping this noobie!

Comment: [This is simpler than you might think](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/11) `[\n\d.]+`

Comment: Remove the newlines before searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove all new line as :

```
ipaddress = ipaddress.replace('\n','')
```

So the below piece of code:

```
ipaddress = "[Blocked IPS] 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 19\n2.168.1.5 192.168.1.6 192.168.1.7 192.168.1.8 192.168.1.9 192.16\n8.1.10 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12 192.168.1.13 192.168.1.14 192.1\n68.1.15 192.168.1.16 192.168.1.17 192.168.1.18 192.168.1.19";
ipaddress = ipaddress.replace('\n','')
print ipaddress
```

will give this output:

```
[Blocked IPS] 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.6 192.168.1.7 192.168.1.8 192.168.1.9 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12 192.168.1.13 192.168.1.14 192.168.1.15 192.168.1.16 192.168.1.17 192.168.1.18 192.168.1.19
```

and then you can use below regex:

```
([\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1bfAdJ/1

Comment: So are you saying I would need to read in the output into a new variable and then remove the new lines from the text prior to running my validation?

The validation process is like this:

(Send Command to FW) --->(Firewalls returns address group as script output) ---> (re.search looks at output for IP) ---> (Script returns pass or fail)